# Simplificar múltiples ifs para reducir código

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con mi programa, la cuestión es que quiero definir reglas en cuanto al posicionamiento de una de las reinas del tablero para que de esta forma solo se mueva a esos espacios definidos, en el programa yo todo lo defino con sentencias de `if` pero mi problema es que al querer convertirlo en dinámico esas sentencias de `if` dejan de funcionar ya que solo están definidas para los primeros espacios de `8*8` y lo que quiero conseguir es que esas reglas vayan cambiando con la cantidad de reinas en el tablero.

**REGLAS DE MOVIMIENTO**

```
    public int[] posicion(MouseEvent evt) {
        int newX = 0, newY;

        if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 25) {
            newX = 25;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 75) {
            newX = 75;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 125) {
            newX = 125;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 175) {
            newX = 175;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 225) {
            newX = 225;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 275) {
            newX = 275;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 325) {
            newX = 325;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 375) {
            newX = 375;
        } else {
            newX = 375;
        }

        if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 25) {
            newY = 25;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 75) {
            newY = 75;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 125) {
            newY = 125;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 175) {
            newY = 175;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 225) {
            newY = 225;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 275) {
            newY = 275;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 325) {
            newY = 325;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 375) {
            newY = 375;
        } else {
            newY = 375;
        }

        int retorno[] = {newX, newY};

        return retorno;
    }
```

**INTENTO**

```
int ite_Uno = 0;
int ite_Dos = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < tablero.length; i++) {
     ite_Uno = 25 * (50 * i);
     if (evt.getXOnScreen() > ite_Dos && evt.getXOnScreen() < ite_Uno) {
         newX = ite_Uno;
     }
     ite_Dos = 25 * (50 * i);
}
```

> Esto fue lo que se me ocurrió pero no funciona y ademas no creo que sea lo mas adecuado ya que la pieza se estará moviendo constantemente y creo que un `for` no es lo mas adecuado pero si logra funcionar con `for` con eso me conformo.

**CODIGO COMPLETO**

```
package tablerojava;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class TableroJava extends JFrame {

    static int reinas = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int anchoAlto = 50;
    int margen = 25;
    int espacio = 50;
    JPanel jpanel = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();
    JLabel ex = new JLabel();
    JLabel label[] = new JLabel[reinas];
    JLabel tablero[][] = new JLabel[reinas][reinas];
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.yellow, 1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        reinas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la cantidad de reinas"));
        TableroJava op = new TableroJava();
        op.setBounds(0, 0, (60 * reinas), (60 * reinas));
        op.setVisible(true);
        op.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public TableroJava() {
        for (int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
            label[i] = new JLabel();
            // r + r + r + r
            label[i].setBounds(margen + (espacio * i), margen, anchoAlto, anchoAlto);
            label[i].setText("Q" + (i + 1));
            label[i].setForeground(Color.red);
            label[i].setBorder(border);
            label[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            label[i].addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
                    arrastreReina(evt);
                }
            });
            label[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
                    movimientoReina(evt);
                }
            });
            jpanel.add(label[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tablero.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tablero.length; j++) {
                tablero[i][j] = new JLabel();
                tablero[i][j].setBounds(margen + (espacio * i), margen + (espacio * j), anchoAlto, anchoAlto);
                tablero[i][j].setBorder(border);

                if ((i%2 == 0) == (j%2 == 0)) {
                    tablero[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                } else {
                    tablero[i][j].setBackground(Color.black);
                }

                tablero[i][j].setOpaque(true);
                tablero[i][j].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                jpanel.add(tablero[i][j]);
            }
        }

        ex.setBounds(margen, margen, anchoAlto, anchoAlto);
        jpanel.add(ex);
    }

    public void arrastreReina(MouseEvent evt) {
        if(evt.getSource() instanceof JLabel) {
            ((JLabel) evt.getSource()).setLocation(posicion(evt)[0], posicion(evt)[1]);
        }
    }

    public void movimientoReina(MouseEvent evt) {
        if(evt.getSource() instanceof JLabel) {
            count++;
            System.out.println("Movimientos: " + count);
        }
    }

    public int[] posicion(MouseEvent evt) {
        int newX = 0, newY;

        if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 25) {
            newX = 25;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 75) {
            newX = 75;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 125) {
            newX = 125;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 175) {
            newX = 175;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 225) {
            newX = 225;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 275) {
            newX = 275;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 325) {
            newX = 325;
        } else if ((evt.getXOnScreen() - 50) <= 375) {
            newX = 375;
        } else {
            newX = 375;
        }

        if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 25) {
            newY = 25;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 75) {
            newY = 75;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 125) {
            newY = 125;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 175) {
            newY = 175;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 225) {
            newY = 225;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 275) {
            newY = 275;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 325) {
            newY = 325;
        } else if ((evt.getYOnScreen() - 50) <= 375) {
            newY = 375;
        } else {
            newY = 375;
        }

        int retorno[] = {newX, newY};

        return retorno;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yo por lo menos no entiendo tu problema. a que te referis con dinamico? que es lo que tratas de hacer? que tiene que ver el for con todos esos if?

Comment: @gbianchi me refiero a que quiero reducir todos esos if de alguna manera y lo intente con un for ya que en general en el programa cuando se ejecuta pido que me den la cantidad de reinas en el tablero y eso aumentara tanto las reinas como los espacios en el tablero y las reglas solo funcionan para los primeros espacios de 8*8 o menores pero cuando agrego mas espacios estas reglas dejan de servir por lo que quiero que de alguna manera esto se vuelva dinamico de acuerdo a la cantidad de espacios agregados al programa en lugar de solamente ser reglas estaticas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La mejor forma que veo de simplificar para este caso es crear un método al cual le pases el valor de `X`  o de `Y`, que él haga el cálculo y te devuelva la posición.

Por ejemplo:

```
public int[] posicion(MouseEvent evt) {
    int newX = getPosition(evt.getXOnScreen());
    int newY = getPosition(evt.getYOnScreen());
    int retorno[] = {newX, newY};
    return retorno;
}

public int getPosition(int mValue) {
    int subValue = mValue - 50;
    if (subValue <= 25) {
        return 25;
    } else if (subValue <= 75) {
        return 75;
    } else if (subValue <= 125) {
        return 125;
    } else if (subValue <= 175) {
        return 175;
    } else if (subValue <= 225) {
        return 225;
    } else if (subValue <= 275) {
        return 275;
    } else if (subValue <= 325) {
        return 325;
    } else if (subValue <= 375) {
        return 375;
    } else {
        return 375;
    }   
}
```